# QCA doesn't load plugins

Tags: linux, qt, qt4.8

I'm tring to compile project that uses qca. I have 2 version of Qt installed 4.8.6 and 5.5. Compiling through 4.8.6. OS: Ubuntu 15.10. Linking with `-lqca`

On this code:

```
QCA::Initializer init;
if(!QCA::isSupported("sha256")) {
    qFatal("SHA256 not supported!");
}
```

I'm quiting on qFatal.
I have libqca2-dev and libqca-plugin-ossl installed, and qcatool2 determines this and show all plugins.

If I try to load it manually via:

```
foreach (QString path, QCA::pluginPaths()) {
        QString fullname = path + "/crypto/libqca-ossl.so";
        QPluginLoader loader(fullname);
        loader.load();
        if (loader.isLoaded())
            break;
        else{
            QString error = loader.errorString();
            qDebug() << error;
        }
    }
```

I got this message:
`"The plugin '/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/plugins/crypto/libqca-ossl.so' uses incompatible Qt library. Expected build key "x86_64 linux g++-5.2.1 full-config", got "x86_64 linux g++-4 full-config"`

Could anyone explain me what does it mean and what can I do to make qca load plugins automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Your error basically tells you, that you are program is build with `g++5.2.1`, but are trying to load a plugin for something built with `g++4`. You will need a plugin with `g++5.2.1` to make it work. Just try to build it yourself.

Please note that QCA does not work with Qt 5.x, only 4.x!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for help!
I tried to build it from `https://github.com/highfidelity/qca` but when I try to load it manually I get the same error